# Multipart file upload via HTTPClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, curl, httpclient

I am trying to convert a post request presented via cURL to c# HTTPClient with an old application using .NETFramework4

The cURL notation of the request from API docs:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' -F file=@/Users/user1/Downloads/download.jpeg -F file_name=nameForFile -F is_shared=true -F targetable_id=1 -F targetable_type=Lead -X POST "https://domain.freshsales.io/api/documents"
```

My C# code, currently taking a file the user uploaded via input type form and trying to upload:

```
var filename = String.Format("status_{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM"));
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file), "file", filename);
            content.Add(new StringContent(filename), "file_name");
            content.Add(new StringContent("true"), "is_shared");
            content.Add(new StringContent(uID), "targetable_id");
            content.Add(new StringContent("Contact"), "targetable_type");
            
            HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"documents") { Content = content };

            return client.SendAsync(req).Result;
        }
```

**For now I always get BadRequest(400)**

In PostMan I am able to get OK(201)..

For more reference this is the code PostMan presents for C# RestSharp (not sure how to fully translate if to HttpClient + byteArrayContent..

```
var client = new RestClient("mydomain.io/api/documents");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Token token=xxx");
request.AddFile("file", "/Users/user1/Desktop/sc.png");
request.AddParameter("targetable_id", "134");
request.AddParameter("targetable_type", "Contact");
request.AddParameter("name", "a.jpg");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Did you compare the HTTP requests, using a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark? See anything different about them? Have you considered using RestSharp instead of HttpClient?

Comment: @mason I don't think I can use RestSharp as this is an old .netFramework4.0

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of .NET? You should upgrade to the latest 4.X version. And you can use [RestSharp 105.2.3](https://www.fuget.org/packages/RestSharp/105.2.3), which supports .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: @mason the thing is that as you can see even in the RestSharp example I posted the .addFile method requires a path to a local file whereas in my application the file comes as Stream / byte array from a form input... So I am really not sure how I should translate it..

Comment: Presumably there's overloads of that method, or another method with a similar name that will accept a byte array. If you just *try it* then Intellisense (you are using Visual Studio, right?) should assist you in locating a suitable method........You still haven't answered my question regarding Fiddler or Wireshark.